# Problema al recorrer un arreglo en javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente problema al recorrer un arreglo desde javascript

```
Var arreglo = [1,2,3];

Arreglo.map(function( item , index ) {
 // en la primera iteracion el valor de item es undefined

Console.log(item);

// y quisiera saber como hago para qye no se muestre el mensaje undefined en su primera iteracion
});
```

Comment: Si claro tienes razon es que ahora acabe de postear mi duda desde el mobil entonces quiso correjirse la A mayuscula entonces por eso quedo distinto entonces lo que succede es que la primera iteracion es undefined y las consiguientes muestran el valor del arreglo

Comment: no tiene por que darte `undefined` en la primera iteracion si es ese el arreglo al que le haces `.map`

Answer (score 1):

Amigo tienes que poner las variables literales por ejemplo poner:

```
Var arreglo = [1,2,3]
```

y es

```
var arreglo = [1,2,3]
```

> el `var` va en minúsculas porque es una palabra reservada de javascript.

También la variable que le pusiste

```
var arreglo
```

y después lo llamas con

```
Arreglo.map(function( item , index ) { 
 console.log(item);
});
```

> El error esta en las mayúsculas, amigo si pones `var Avion` al llamar pon `Avion` osea igual.

Otro detalle es al poner

```
Console.log(...)
```

la function se usa así

```
console.log(...)
```

> Con la letra (`c`) en minúsculas.

**Ejemplo funcional**

```js
var arreglo = [1,2,3];

arreglo.map(function( item , index ) { 

console.log(item);

 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Tienes dos errores;

> 1- Abajo llamas a **Arreglo** en vez de **arreglo** que es el que defines.
>
> 2- La palabra reservada `var` es con minuscula

correctamente seria asi:

```js
    var arreglo = [1,2,3];

        arreglo.map(function( item,index) {
        console.log(item);
     });
```